# how do I force textView containing ltr characters, to right aligned on rtl enviroment

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

all "lines" uses the same struct (width, height, gravity, ...:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/labelMkt1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"   // I also tried "center_vertical|start"
     android:text="@string/report_mkt"                       
     android:textColor="#000" /> <!-- force gravity start, textAlignment=textStart, did not work, useful for RTL layout with EN characters -->

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelMkt2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/device_param_empty" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but when label1 contains English characters (e.g. "MKT") , the text is aligned left.

[image: mkt is left aligned]

- I tried to use `android:gravity="center_vertical|start"` (although "start" is the default) and it did not help.
- I tried to add `android:textAlignment="textStart"` and it did not help.

**How can I force label1 to align right, as all other labels?**

Answer (score 5):

You can use `android:textDirection="rtl"` so no matter if the text is in Hebrew or English it will start from the right side of your view and won't jump to the other direction when you change the language.

**Note -** I think that `android:gravity` didn't work for you because Hebrew is written rtl and English is written ltr. 
 **so** when you put gravity - start and the language is English your text will start from the left side of your view.

**Edit with a working example:**

**Layout:**

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelMkt1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/report_mkt"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textDirection="rtl" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelMkt2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/device_param_empty"
    android:textDirection="rtl" />
```

**String resources:**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string name="report_mkt">this is english text</string>
<string name="device_param_empty">this is english text</string>
```

**How it looks on a real phone:**

[image]

So as you can see I too got my strings in English and everything is working fine, so the problem is not from having English strings.

Comment: It does work. but this solution only works if my language is RTL. [I can test in code: if isRTL then textView.setTextDirection, but I prefer a solution that works for all localizations]

Comment: But I have tested this both in Hebrew and English and in both times the text started from the right of the view - I think that my solution will work for you

Comment: Hey @Atara, I too had strings in English and it is right aligned - I edited my answer, feel free to check it and tell me if your problem is not fixed with my edited answer.

Comment: If your layout is in Relative or Constraint layouts, just simply align to parent view

Comment: @TamirAbutbul, Thanks for your efforts. In LTR-English I prefer all strings to be aligned left. In RTL-Hebrew I prefer all strings to be aligned right (including the specific English "MKT" term. so your solution works well on my RTL. but not in my LTR, and the layout should work in both LTR and RTL cases, so if I do not get another solution, I will slve it in code, using your hint. thanks!

Comment: @ATara Oh ok , now i understand your question - so yes my solution will not fully cover your case. As you said it will only cover 1 aspect - comment here if you can find the solution without using java (you got me interested as well)

Comment: I would add a separate layout XML for RTL locales, even if the difference is only a few textDirection attributes.

Comment: another code solution, more general - append control characters - https://ubuntudroid.github.io/2015/01/11/handling-ltr-text-in-rtl-environments.html

Answer (score 3):

If your system language is RTL, You can force ltr languages to align as rtl by using

```
android:textDirection="locale"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
```

and text will be aligned regardless of its content, but still depended on the layout direction.

The Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:textAlignment):

> Align to the end of the view, which is ALIGN_RIGHT if the view's
> resolved layoutDirection is LTR, and ALIGN_LEFT otherwise.